# I am not able to build .so file

Tags: android, python, windows, tensorflow, bazel

I am trying to make an app for object detection using tensorflow and I am following the instructions as listed in this website:

https://www.skcript.com/svr/realtime-object-and-face-detection-in-android-using-tensorflow-object-detection-api/

But I have run into build errors.

I am making an android application for detecting objects using tensorflow API and I have followed all steps as mentioned in the above link. I am using Windows 10 for coding, not any Linux distro. I tried building the app using bazel but there are build errors.

Here's the command as instructed from the above website:

```
bazel build -c opt //tensorflow/contrib/android:libtensorflow_inference.so --crosstool_top=//external:android/crosstool --host_crosstool_top=@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:toolchain --cpu=armeabi-v7a
```

After running, it starts compiling and does 1069 processes, but after reaching 1068/1069 it displays the following:

```
ERROR: C:/sri/sritrain/tensorflow-master/tensorflow/contrib/android/BUILD:60:1: Linking of rule '//tensorflow/contrib/android:libtensorflow_inference.so' failed (Exit 1)
external/androidndk/ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin\ld: fatal error: bazel-out/armeabi-v7a-opt/bin/tensorflow/core/kernels/libandroid_tensorflow_kernels.lo: pread failed: Invalid argument
clang.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
Target //tensorflow/contrib/android:libtensorflow_inference.so failed to build
Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
INFO: Elapsed time: 3148.512s, Critical Path: 443.26s
INFO: 1045 processes: 1045 local.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

I scoured through the internet and found a small modification so I typed:

```
bazel build -c opt //tensorflow/contrib/android:libtensorflow_inference.so --crosstool_top=//external:android/crosstool --host_crosstool_top=@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:toolchain --cpu=armeabi-v7a --cxxopt=-std=c++11
```

However this returns an error even before the previous command did:

```
ERROR: C:/sri/sritrain/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/android/BUILD:60:1: Linking of rule '//tensorflow/contrib/android:libtensorflow_inference.so' failed (Exit 1)
external/androidndk/ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin\ld: fatal error: bazel-out/armeabi-v7a-opt/bin/tensorflow/core/kernels/libandroid_tensorflow_kernels.lo: pread failed: Invalid argument
clang.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
Target //tensorflow/contrib/android:libtensorflow_inference.so failed to build
Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
INFO: Elapsed time: 2787.155s, Critical Path: 244.57s
INFO: 795 processes: 795 local.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

It is supposed to create a .so file on my computer but it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I SOLVED IT!
I found the problem was that i was using the ndk-bundle from under Android Studio's folder and it was the latest ndk. I downloaded an older ndk version android_ndk_r15c and ran the command:

```
bazel build -c opt //tensorflow/contrib/android:libtensorflow_inference.so --crosstool_top=//external:android/crosstool --host_crosstool_top=@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:toolchain --cpu=armeabi-v7a --cxxopt=-std=c++11
```

So the build was completed successfully!